# My application crashes tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

After a while and requesting multiple pages I am getting the following error.
How can I fix this?

`May 26, 2011 1:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Api threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1472)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at de.giz.ff.domain.Subject.findSubject(Subject.java:139)
    at de.giz.ff.domain.Question.getSubjectName(Question.java:354)
    at de.giz.ff.server.Api.doFetch(Api.java:66)
    at de.giz.ff.server.Api.doGet(Api.java:199)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:427)
May 26, 2011 1:02:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.ArrayList de.giz.ff.client.FrageFunktionService.getTextsAndRights(int,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilterPrincipal(Unknown Source)
    at waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.<init>(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at de.giz.ff.domain.Client.findClient(Client.java:49)
    at de.giz.ff.server.FrageFunktionServiceImpl.getTextsAndRights(FrageFunktionServiceImpl.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    ... 21 more`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading [VisualVM 1.3.2](http://visualvm.java.net/relnotes.html), installing all its plugings, and pointing it at your Tomcat app to see what's happening.  It'll let you see the different memory generations, what objects are being allocated, what threads are running, etc.  It's a wealth of information.

I see Hibernate and SQL Server in your stack trace.  I'm betting that Hibernate reflection is rapidly filling up your perm space.

Comment: In addition to this, adding the start-up flag -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError will show the contents of the heap when the oom was thrown. [docs] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gdyrr

Comment: Nice comment, Sean.  I'd surely vote it up if it was an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application is using too much memory. You could try increasing the amount of memory Tomcat is allocated.  If you installed Tomcat on Windows as a service it's fairly easy to do this using the Tomcat monitor, otherwise I think you will need to edit a [config file](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory#Q1).

I should point out that if your application has a memory leak, however much memory you allocate Tomcat it will eventually crash. You should check your application as well to ensure you're not creating lots of objects in memory which cannot be destroyed.

Comment: How can I find a memory leak?

Comment: you need a tool, like VisualVM, that can show you how your memory is evolving over time.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your Garbage Collector cant allow more memory, try to allow more memory in the setenv.sh or you may have a memory leak